# Does react native code get compiled differently depending on the platform?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, metro-bundler

I've started learning react native and trying to understand the architecture, I'm a bit confused by a few things I've read. I get that the react-native code is bundled by the metro bundler into a single JS file which is packaged into an app. The following comment in a medium article gave me some doubts

> Binaries and JS bundle will eventually be packed inside an executable file for targeted platform.

I have 2 questions, firstly does the JS code itself get bundled differently or customised depending on whether the platform is ios or android, or in theory it should be the exact same JS bundle?
Secondly, most examples I've seen, mention Java/Objective-c native code and the react-native code being bundled together and communicating via a bridge, but can an app be fully written in react-native e.g. a simple static page so that there is no native code needed? In this scenario would the package just be a bundled JS file which would be the same for ios and android?